# How to forward all requests starting with a specific folder name to the same folder

Tags: redirect, htaccess

In my Wordpress website main directory, I created a folder `servers`, which contains two files `.htaccess` & `index.php`.

In the `.htaccess` file, I add those lines to redirect all requests to that folder to the `index.php` file.

```
# Enable rewriting.
RewriteEngine on

# Optional: do not allow perusal of directories.
Options -Indexes

# Optional: explicitly enable per-directory rewrites in the .htaccess context.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Required when not in the webroot. Always use a trailing slash.
RewriteBase /

# To be able to access existing directories and files (standalone scripts).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Redirect everything else to index.php.
# Add QSA to ensure that querystring variables are registered as such.
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

So whenever a user requests a link like `example.com`, `example.com/foo` or `example.com/foo/bar`, the default Wordpress website should load. and when I request any url that starts with the `servers` folder: `example.com/servers`, `example.com/servers/foo`, `example.com/servers/foo/bar`, I want the `example/com/servers/index.php` file to be executed.

The current `example.com/servers/.htaccess` file only executes this url `example.com/servers` with the `example.com/servers/index.php` file but it's not executing other urls that start with the `servers` folder(`example.com/servers/foo`, `example.com/servers/foo/bar`) by the `example.com/servers/index.php` file.

How can edit the htaccess file so that all request to `example.com/servers/*` are executed by the `example.com/servers/index.php` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you don't need the .htaccess in the servers directory itself. You can remove this and apache can use rules in the root Wordpress .htaccess to do the rewrite you need, and you can usefully keep rewrite rules for your site in one place.

You need a couple of rules to make this work:

```
RewriteRule ^servers/index.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^servers/(.*) servers/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

These say:

1. If we're already requesting a page that starts with servers/index.php then quit process rewrite rules. This is there to stop redirect loop errors
2. Any pages that start with servers/, redirect to servers/index.php, passing everything that was originally after servers/ to a parameter in index.php if you need it. E.g. this will send servers/foo/bar to servers/index.php?page=foo/bar

Edit: You need to place these rules before any other RewriteRules or RewriteCond statements so that they get processed first.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> # Required when not in the webroot. Always use a trailing slash.
> RewriteBase /
> ```

Your `RewriteBase /` directive is resulting in all requests (except `/server/` itself<sup>***1**</sup>) being rewritten back to the document root. ie. `/index.php`, not `/server/index.php` as intended.

*Aside:* I would add, that *comment* is simply not true. It depends what you are doing. In fact, more often than not, the `RewriteBase` directive should be omitted entirely (as is the case here).

(<sup>***1**</sup> Requests for `/server/` "work" because the regex `.` on the `RewriteRule` directive fails and the request is then left for mod_dir to issue an internal subrequest for `index.php` - the `DirectoryIndex` - in the current directory.)

You need to either:

- Remove this `RewriteBase` directive altogether - since you are rewriting to `index.php` (relative path) in the current directory anyway (default behaviour).
- Or, explicitly set `RewriteBase /server`. (But that is mostly redundant.)